# Is it possible for one app to be listed multiple times as an Android share option (YouTube play & queue)

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I am wondering if it's possible for my Android app to show 2 different 'share' options under YouTube's "share" (app picker) dialog?

My app is accepting an Android intent to get the shared URLs, but I would like to offer two share options within YouTube's app-picker dialog, one to directly **play** the URL and another to **queue** the URL (I don't want to display an additional dialog in my app).

Currently, in the app's manifest file, I specify :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.xxx.XX_Remote"
        android:versionCode="202"
        android:versionName="2.0.2"
        android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="False" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False" 
        android:label="XX Remote" 
        android:debuggable="True" 
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">
        
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="XX Remote"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="XX_Remote" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
            <intent-filter android:label="Play in XX">  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter> 
            <intent-filter android:label="Queue in X">  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

However, the second (queue) intent doesn't show up at all.

And if it did show up, I'm not sure how to read the intent's label by code so I can distinguish between the two intents.

Comment: Posted the full manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `<activity>` tag cannot match multiple intent filters simultaneously.

For that purpose you can use [`<activity-alias>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element) in your manifest which presents same activity as a separate entity:

```
<activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
          android:label="XX Remote"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
          android:value="XX_Remote" />
    <intent-filter>  
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- use only one intent filter for SEND action in activity tag-->
    <intent-filter android:label="Play in XX">  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
<!-- note that we will use android:name for resolving if this alias was used to start activity -->
<activity-alias
        android:targetActivity=".com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
        android:name=".com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity.Queue">
    <!-- Put second SEND action inside activity-alias tag -->
    <intent-filter android:label="Queue in X">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

Then inside your activity you can resolve if it was started through alias by checking intents component:

```
// inside onCreate and/or onNewIntent (after resolving that intent action is SEND):

if (intent.component.className.endsWith(".Queue"){
    // putting data in the queue...
} else {
    // playing requested data...
}
```

Comment: This works with the exception that the answer contains a "." in-front of the name/targetActivity which triggered an error in my dev. environment (Delphi).  Removing the extra period fixed the issue for me.