# Use of <activity-alias> to show different launcher for my app

Tags: android-intent, android-manifest, android-implicit-intent, android-activity-alias

I have a MainActivity in my app. I want my MainActivity through the implicit intent.Also, I want user should have two options to come to my app as I have two cases for both two otpions. I am using  as shown below but unable to see two options for my app when user tries to share.

kindly help me to achieve the solution

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:allowEmbedded="true"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:resizeableActivity="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/OTPTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:path="/main_activity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".MyShareActivity"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:label="Random Text">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:path="/share_activity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to the `<intent-filter>` for the `<activity-alias>`.

Here's a note from the documentation for `<category>`:

> Note: To receive implicit intents, you must include the
> CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods
> `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` treat all intents as if
> they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you don't declare it
> in your intent filter, no implicit intents can resolve your activity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @David Wasser. But, it did not solve my problem as sharing option is again showing only one option(label = @string/title_activity_main) for my app launcher.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your updated manifest.

Comment: According to this post, this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740954/is-it-possible-for-one-app-to-be-listed-multiple-times-as-an-android-share-optio

Comment: Thanks @david. This post helped me to solve my problem